# Libgdx how can I add FreeType extension?

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx, freetype

I have tried with the maven thing, but it won't work.I probably wrote the wrong line in the dependencies or something.
This is the link [maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/search?q=libgdx).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy way: Make sure you checked the "Freetype" extension in the gdx-setup app, before project generation.

Otherwise you can add it to your already created project the following way:

In build.gradle of your root project, just add the following dependencies:

desktop:

```
compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
```

android:

```
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
```

ios:

```
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
```

html: not compatible, im afraid

core:

```
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
```

Comment: Hae juan, i can't solve the above ERROR: Could not get unknown property 'gdxVersion' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: I have struggled to add the following depencies almost a week . Anybody who can help do the same, because i'm making android video app and drawtext doesn't work at all because it is lacking the freetype lib

Answer (score -1):

Adding gdx freetype extension is a very easy process . please go through the link . you can definitely implement it.

[freetype extension](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype)

If you want to implement the tty fonts, just download the latest version of "hiero"

By using "hiero" you can easily make the fonts as per your design skills.